# Setting Border background with a template binding

Tags: silverlight, colors, background, templatebinding

Value="{TemplateBinding HeaderColor}"I've created my own control, and I'm wondering if I can bind a Border.Background to a template property. Currently i'm setting it with a StaticResource like the following:

```
<Color x:Key="ControlMouseOverColor">green</Color>

<ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="headerLayout">
    <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:6" Value="{StaticResource ControlMouseOverColor}" />
</ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
```

I'd like it be a property on my control, and be able to set it as a template binding

```
<ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="headerLayout">
    <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:6" Value="{TemplateBinding HeaderColor}" />
</ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
```

MainPage.xaml

```
<ctrl:Selection Grid.Column="0" HeaderColor="Red" HeaderText="Header Text" />
```

my class:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty HeaderColorProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("HeaderColor", typeof(System.Windows.Media.Color), typeof(Selection), new PropertyMetadata(System.Windows.Media.Colors.Red));

public  System.Windows.Media.Color HeaderColor {
    get { return (System.Windows.Media.Color)GetValue(HeaderColorProperty); }
    set { SetValue(HeaderColorProperty, value); }
}
```

This 2nd option does not work, should I be able to do this? I don't get an error, it just does not change to the color I set.

Comment left by AngelWPF asked for more code, pasting below, I'm in the beginning stages of learning to create a control, wanted to note that, because there is a lot I have not got to yet, one piece at a time :)

generic.xaml

```
<ResourceDictionary
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:SelectionControl.Library"
xmlns:ctrl="clr-namespace:SelectionControl.Library;assembly=SelectionControl">

<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="HeaderBackground" EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
    <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0" />
    <GradientStop Color="Gray" Offset="1" />
</LinearGradientBrush>

<Color x:Key="ControlMouseEnterColor">aliceblue</Color>
<Color x:Key="ControlMouseLeaveColor">Gray</Color>
<Color x:Key="ControlLeftMouseUpColor">Red</Color>

<Style TargetType="ctrl:Selection">
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="Auto" />
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="Auto" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12" />
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="AliceBlue" />
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2,2,2,2" />

    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ResourceKey=HeaderBackground}" />

    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ctrl:Selection">
                <Grid x:Name="RootElement" Margin="{TemplateBinding Margin}">
                    <!-- Visual States -->
                     <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                          <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="MouseEnter">
                              <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="headerLayout">
                                        <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:.5" Value="{TemplateBinding HeaderColor}" />
                                    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                              </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="MouseLeave">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="headerLayout">
                                        <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="{StaticResource ControlMouseLeaveColor}" />
                                    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="MouseLeftUp">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="headerLayout">
                                        <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="{StaticResource ControlLeftMouseUpColor}" />
                                    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <!-- End Visual States-->

                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <!-- Header -->
                    <Border x:Name="headerLayout" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" CornerRadius="2,2,2,2" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
                        <StackPanel>
                            <ToggleButton ></ToggleButton>
                            <TextBlock Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Text="{TemplateBinding HeaderText}" FontWeight="{TemplateBinding FontWeight}" FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Border>
                    <!-- Body Content -->
                    <ContentPresenter Grid.Row="1" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Selection.cs

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace SelectionControl.Library {
    [TemplateVisualState(Name = Selection.MouseEnterStateName, GroupName = Selection.CommonStatesGroupName)]
    [TemplateVisualState(Name = Selection.MouseLeaveStateName, GroupName = Selection.CommonStatesGroupName)]
    [TemplateVisualState(Name = Selection.MouseLeftUpStateName, GroupName = Selection.CommonStatesGroupName)]

public class Selection : ContentControl {
    public const string CommonStatesGroupName = "CommonStates";
    public const string MouseEnterStateName = "MouseEnter";
    public const string MouseLeaveStateName = "MouseLeave";
    public const string MouseLeftUpStateName = "MouseLeftUp";

    public Selection() {
        this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(Selection);

        this.MouseEnter += new MouseEventHandler(OnMouseEnter);
        this.MouseLeave += new MouseEventHandler(OnMouseLeave);
        this.MouseLeftButtonUp += new MouseButtonEventHandler(OnMouseLeftButtonUp);
    }

    void OnMouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) {
        this.GoToState(Selection.MouseLeftUpStateName, true);
    }

    void OnMouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
        this.GoToState(Selection.MouseLeaveStateName, true);
    }

    void OnMouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
        this.GoToState(Selection.MouseEnterStateName, true);
    }
    private void GoToState(string stateName, bool useTransitions) {
        VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, stateName, useTransitions);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty HeaderTextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("HeaderText", typeof(string), typeof(Selection), new PropertyMetadata(""));

    public string HeaderText {
        get { return (string)GetValue(HeaderTextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(HeaderTextProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty HeaderColorProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("HeaderColor", typeof(System.Windows.Media.Color), typeof(Selection), new PropertyMetadata(System.Windows.Media.Colors.Red));

    public  System.Windows.Media.Color HeaderColor {
        get { return (System.Windows.Media.Color)GetValue(HeaderColorProperty); }
        set { SetValue(HeaderColorProperty, value); }
    }
}}
```

Comment: can you post more code? where in your XAML are you using this ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames actually? Inside the control template of the Selection control? If so, the TemplateBinding should work!

Comment: Hi AngelWPF I added the code in my generic.xaml file, and the code in my control class below my original question. Thanks for any help. Yes I'm using the ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames inside my template, I'm betting i'm missing something obvious.

Comment: Can you observe if the template binding is failing in your visual studio output window? Do you receive binding errors when the animation is supposed to run? If you are, then you can try replacing template binding with normal binding and use RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ctrl:Selection}} insetad...

Comment: I'm not seeing any issues in the output window, would the RelativeSource allow me to set to my headerColor property?

Comment: Can you try normal binding and use RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ctrl:Selection}} instead of TemplateBinding?

Comment: I can, but I've not used this, and don't understand how it would link it to HeaderColor property. are you saying: instead of <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:.5" Value="{TemplateBinding HeaderColor}" />   , use <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:.5" Value="RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ctrl:Selection}} " />

Comment: Nope it should be <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:.5" Value="{Binding Path=HeaderColor, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ctrl:Selection}}}" />

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have had mixed results using TemplateBinding on custom dependency properties.  Because of this, I have used RelativeSource TemplatedParent which seems to work in every situation.

```
<EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:.5" Value="{Binding HeaderColor, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
```